# Using mongoose to update a trip

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have been following [the docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) on how to update a trip using Node.js,mongoose,express, as well as a couple of stack overflow questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024787/update-model-with-mongoose-express-nodejs) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25116522/mongoose-findoneandupdate-and-upsert-returns-no-errs-no-documents-affected).

Inside of my Controller I originally had a save, which was working, but I needed to switch it to an update. When I run the code, nothing breaks and the `place` is properly logged to the console as I would expect, which further indicates that the code is being run, but for some reason it isn't overwriting the item that has the same placeIdentifier.

What am I doing wrong that prevents this from updating?

My controller:

```
var place = {
    identifier: placeIdentifier,
    name: placeName,
    location: Location,
    travelStart: startDate,
    travelEnd: endDate,
}

Place.findOneAndUpdate(
    {identifier:placeIdentifier}, 
    { $set: place }, 
    {upsert: true},
    function() {
        console.log(place)
        console.log("place saved...")
    }   
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I got it. Or rather, this person got it: [Mongoose: Find, modify, save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14199529/mongoose-find-modify-save)

```
User.findOne({username: oldUsername}, function (err, user) {
    user.username = newUser.username;
    user.password = newUser.password;
    user.rights = newUser.rights;

    user.save(function (err) {
        if(err) {
            console.error('ERROR!');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm just changing a few things (putting in "Place" instead of "User", etc.).